# T-SQL How to list rows not present in table based on columns from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Looking for some help in what is likely quite a simple problem but the wording makes it hard for me to see if a similar question has been asked.

In SQL Server I have 3 tables:

- `Colleague (ColleagueID (INT), Name (NVARCHAR), Branch`)
- `Module (ModuleID (INT), Course (NVARCHAR), DueDate)`
- `ModuleCompletion (RecordID (INT), Colleague (NVARCHAR), Module (NVARCHAR)`

This is a quickly constructed set of tables based on the data collected previously which the company stored in Excel, e.g. A Worksheet Matrix of (Colleagues Down Y) and (Modules Across X) and a 1 for completed and a 0 for not completed.

I grabbed all the 1's and uploaded them to a ModuleCompletion table to keep track of who completed what.
As it stands there are no Foreign Keys linking the tables and no UNIQUES etc.

Example tables:

**Colleague**

```
ID   Name  Branch  
-----------------
1    xyz    HO  
2    abc    HO  
3    tuv    HO  
4    efg    Branch1
```

**Module**

```
ID   Course  DueDate  
-----------------------
1    Co1     2019-12-31  
2    Co2     2020-01-30
```

**ModuleCompletion**

```
ID   Colleague  Module
-----------------------
1    xyz        Co1
2    xyz        Co2
3    abc        Co1
4    tuv        Co2
```

What I am looking to have returned is:

```
Module  Branch   Colleague
--------------------------
Co1     HO       tuv
Co1     Branch1  efg
Co2     HO       abc
Co2     Branch1  efg
```

The result set should be each Branch and colleague combination not listed with a Module in the `ModuleCompletion` table.

Using:

```sql
SELECT c.Branch, c.Name
FROM Colleague c
LEFT JOIN ModuleCompletion x ON x.Colleague = c.Name 
WHERE x.Colleague IS NULL
ORDER BY c.Branch, c.Name
```

Displays all branch and colleague names where they have completed no courses, e.g. the Colleague name never appears in the `ModuleCompletion` table, but I need it to check by module.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't left join, but cross join.

```
from Colleague c
cross join Module m
where not exists (
  select *
  from ModuleCompletion mc
  where c.Name   = mc.Colleague
  and   m.Course = mc.Module
)
```

Basically you can play on from here

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous solution and to avoid nested select you could do something like that too:

```
SELECT m.Course, c.Branch, c.Name 
  FROM Collegue     as c
 CROSS JOIN Module  as m
EXCEPT 
SELECT m.Course, c.Branch, c.Name
  FROM ModuleCompletion as mc
 INNER JOIN Collegue    as c 
         ON c.Name      = mc.Colleague
 INNER JOIN Module      as m
         ON m.Course    = mc.Module
```

Comment: I can confirm this works as well as the first answer. The dataset is so small at present (a few thousand rows) so it is difficult to calculate relative speeds.